# Dragons Won't Give Dragon Souls

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've killed many dragons in Skyrim. But whenever I kill one, it never gives me their soul. I've been playing on the missions with Miraak and to complete a mission I need to use a shout. But I can't, because I have no dragon souls.
Is there any way to fix this?

I've looked here and this didn't help me. [Why can't I absorb a dragon soul?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115648/)

I'm playing on a PC with no mods.

Comment: Are you on PC or a console? Do you have any mods? Have you tried the suggestions on that page? How much of the main quest have you done? Did you fight that dragon at the western watchtower near Whiterun?

Comment: Im playing on a pc.. no mods.. In the main quest i just did the stuff with areingar. and on the westwern tower i used a setstage command.

Comment: and no unoffical patches. i play on legendary edition so i have all the dlc

Comment: If you’ve been unable to absorb souls from the start of the game... you could try installing the unofficial patches. At this point, you could just give yourself dragon souls in the console, but you’d have to do that every time you kill a dragon for the rest of the game.

Comment: Did you use a setstage command at the western watchtower because you were unable to absorb the dragon’s soul, or because you just wanted to finish it faster?

Comment: What setstage command did you run? UESP says that you sometimes can't absorb souls with Dragonborn installed, unless you have the unofficial patch. You can work around it with `setstage MQ104 90`. Or is that the command you ran already?

Comment: setstage MQ104 90 was the command i used.

Comment: +amaranth i couldnt finish the quest because the dragon soul wouldnt absorb. so i used a setstage command

Comment: I would try installing [USLEEP](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/71214/?), and use the load order they give. I haven't been able to figure out a console command to enable absorbing dragon souls, but you could use `player.modav dragonsouls 3` (or whatever number) to give yourself some souls.

Comment: @amaranth Sounds like you found the answer (“you're suffering the bug that the unofficial patches are made to fix”), and could post that in a proper answer post.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I get the impression that the problem listed on the mod page is caused by an incorrect installation of the patch, not that it’s a vanilla bug that’s fixed by the patch. The OP said that he isn’t using mods, so I don’t know whether his problem would be fixed by the unofficial patch or not. Still, he should install it either way.

Comment: Related: [Miraak stole all my dragon souls](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/198838/4797) (might be a duplicate, but not sure)

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you have been doing missions with Miraak, which is part of the Dragonborn DLC. After reaching a certain point in the DLC, you will not be able to gain dragon souls from dragons as this is important to the DLC's story. You must complete the questline to be able to acquire dragon souls again.

Comment: but i didnt evan recive the soul from the first time i fought a dragon in whiterun.

Comment: i didnt evan start the mirak mission intell weeks after

Comment: But you have started it now? If you can complete the DLC storyline, you might be able to acquire dragon souls again. Otherwise, you might need to resort to console commands.

Comment: i tried finishing the dragonborn quest but at the end mirrak cant aborb the souls..